# Java: ScrollablePicture make it scroll with given coordinates

Tags: java, swing, coordinates, jframe, scrollable

I'm trying to adapt the following example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/components-ScrollDemoProject.zip

The purpose of i want to do is **to allow the user to navigate on a picture to a coordinate they choose themselves** (but not by mouse). So you have a large picture, and only a small part is showing and this window over the picture moves. This works when using the mouse (see the example of oracle). But i want to do this with coordinates that the user chooses.

In the **ScrollablePicture** class you can see that it is possible to **move the picture by dragging the mouse** :

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
    scrollRectToVisible(r);
}
```

I tried to do the same, so **i added this method underneath the mouseDragged function** :

```
public void moveMap(float X, float Y){

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int)X,(int) Y, 1, 1);
    System.err.println("Scroll to "+ r.x);
    scrollRectToVisible(r);
}
```

When i look at my output i can see that **i get coordinates** in the method. But the window is **not scrolling**. My question now is: **Why isn't it scrolling and how do i fix this ?**

Ps: It has nothing to do with the values. Because i tried with fixed numbers in both of the function e.g :

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(2000,2000, 1, 1);
```

It worked in the mouseDragged function but not in the moveMap function

Comment: Your method `moveMap` works the same way as `mouseDragged` in the example. What is the problem?

Comment: So when you pass coordinates to the moveMap it moves to that location ?

Comment: Would you mind trying not to call it from mouseDragged or any mouseEvent ?

Comment: Ok I'll test it when i got some time left :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine.

**Here is how you can test it:**

In the class `ScrollDemo` make the pictrue `public`:

```
public ScrollablePicture picture;
```

In `createAndShowGUI()` change type of the variable `JComponent newContentPane` to:

```
ScrollDemo newContentPane = new ScrollDemo();
```

After `frame.setVisible(true);` call your `moveMap` method:

```
frame.setVisible(true);
    
newContentPane.picture.moveMap(1, 250);
```

Now you can see that the picture is scrolled down so the pixel at `(1, 250)` is visible:

[image]

*Left side: without the `moveMap(1, 250);` call. Right side: with the call. - The moment after start of the application.*

Comment: @Ojtwist curious - what was the problem?

Comment: change type of the variable JComponent newContentPane to:

ScrollDemo newContentPane = new ScrollDemo();. This fixed it . Had to be the ScollDemo class and not a JComponent, it seems

Answer (score 1):

you could moving with coordinates from `JViewPort`, then you code should be

```
final JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)X,(int) Y, 1, 1);
Rectangle r2 = viewport.getVisibleRect();
contentsInTheJScrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(rect.x, rect.y, 
     (int) r2.getWidth(), (int) r2.getHeight()));
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. But would you mind being more specific for the example given in the question. Because in the scrollablePicture class where my moveMap is, there is no scrollPane. (Example code : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/components-ScrollDemoProject.zip).